# urllib2: How to install both proxy and http basic auth handlers as openers?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-2.4

**Background:** Due to the environment limitation I am stuck with python 2.4. So `requests` is out of the question.

I want to be able to use `urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler` and `ProxyHandler` at the same time to open a url.

If I do something like:

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://myproxy.local'})
proxy_opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)

...
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pass_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
...
 urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener([proxy_opener, pass_handler]))
```

The code will stuck at this line:

```
urllib2.urlopen(target_url)
```

So, What is the proper way to install two handlers?

**EDIT:**

My original version has a syntax error. The line

```
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(pass_handler), proxy_opener)
```

should be

```
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(pass_handler, proxy_opener)) # note the parenthesis
```

But as **atupal** suggests, it should be

```
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener([proxy_opener, pass_handler]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [docs-install_opener](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener) and [docs-build_opener](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.build_opener)

`urllib2.install_opener(opener)`

> Install **an** OpenerDirector instance as the default global opener.

and `urllib2.build_opener([handler, ...])`

> Return an OpenerDirector instance, which chains the handlers in the order given. handlers can be either instances of BaseHandler, or subclasses of BaseHandler (in which case it must be possible to call the constructor without any parameters). Instances of the following classes will be **in front of the handlers**, unless the handlers contain them, instances of them or subclasses of them: **ProxyHandler** (if proxy settings are detected), UnknownHandler, HTTPHandler, HTTPDefaultErrorHandler, HTTPRedirectHandler, FTPHandler, FileHandler, HTTPErrorProcessor.

So you should first build a opener use the proxy handler and auth handler. And install it globaly if you want:

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://myproxy.local'})

...
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
pass_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
...
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, pass_handler))
```

**Update:**
I test the following snippet, and it works as expect. Don't forget replace the proxy, url, username and password with your own:

```
import urllib2

proxyhandler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://219.93.183.106:8080'})

url = "http://atupal.org:9001"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, "myusername", "mypassword")
pass_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(
    proxyhandler,
    pass_handler,
    )
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

print urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your code causes this exception: 
AttributeError: OpenerDirector instance has no attribute 'add_parent'. If I switched to urllib2.build_opener([proxy_opener, pass_handler]), the exception is gone, but the code stuck at urllib2.urlopen. I will update my question to reflect the status.

Comment: @AnthonyKong oh, I fix the wrong. Don't need a list, we should use proxy_handler but not proxy_opener. And I add a example, :), It works for me.